# Python coverage used in Django takes too long to execute even though it is run with --source flag option

Tags: python, django, coverage.py, django-tests

I am using the Python package in combination with the Django testing framework and sometimes want to test only one app/directory/package stated in the coverage --source option.

```
coverage run --source='custom_auth' manage.py test custom_auth.tests.TestAuth.test_authentication --keepdb
```

Is this command the correct way to run only one test? I am also using --keepdb command to ignore recreating the database again.
The test is executed in 0.147s, but something happens behind/before the test, and it takes about 3-5 minutes to start executing the test.

Comment: run your test with -v 2  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-verbosity to show the full message and see what running

Comment: Command got stuck at line: "Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply." I do not want to use any migration file since I pass option --keepdb, if I am right that means that I do not want to recreate the database, so I do not know what is the purpose of migration files while testing.

Comment: The --source argument doesn't limit what tests get run, it limits what source gets considered when reporting.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I put custom_auth.tests.TestAuth.test_authentication after manage.py test, so that needs to run only that one test method.

Answer (score 0):

The other way, which may be easier to remember, is to tag your tests

```
from django.test import tag

class Tests(TestCase):


    @tag('eu')
    def test_001_default(self):        
    ...
    @tag('eu','invoice')
    def test001_invoice(self):
    ...
    @tag('eu','shipment', 'slow')
    def test_001_shipment(self): 
    ...
```

Then

```
./manage.py test --keepdb whatever.tests --tag=eu
```

or

```
./manage.py test --keepdb whatever.tests.name.Tests --tag=eu --exclude-tag=slow
```

etc.